# Flume solrSink, No error but does not ingest the data to Solr

Tags: solr, flume

I am indexing text document using Flume, I do not see any error or warning message but data is not getting ingested to Solr Log level for both Solr and Flume is set to TRACE, ALL

```
Flume version : 1.5.2.2.3
Solr Version : 5.5

**Config files are as below**

   **Flume Config :**

agent.sources = SpoolDirSrc
agent.channels = FileChannel
agent.sinks = SolrSink

# Configure Source
agent.sources.SpoolDirSrc.channels = fileChannel agent.sources.SpoolDirSrc.type = spooldir
```

agent.sources.SpoolDirSrc.spoolDir = /home/flume/source_emails agent.sources.SpoolDirSrc.basenameHeader = true agent.sources.SpoolDirSrc.fileHeader = true 
agent.sources.SpoolDirSrc.deserializer =org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder
agent.channels.FileChannel.type = file agent.channels.FileChannel.capacity = 10000 
agent.sinks.SolrSink.type = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineSolrSink
agent.sinks.SolrSink.morphlineFile = /etc/flume/conf/morphline.conf agent.sinks.SolrSink.batchsize = 1000 agent.sinks.SolrSink.batchDurationMillis = 2500 agent.sinks.SolrSink.channel = fileChannel agent.sinks.SolrSink.morphlineId = morphline1 agent.sources.SpoolDirSrc.channels = FileChannel agent.sinks.SolrSink.channel = FileChannel

"
    **Morphline Config**

```
solrLocator: {
collection : gsearch

zkHost : "codesolr-as-r3p:21810,codesolr-as-r3p:21811,codesolr-as-r3p:21812"
}
morphlines :
[
  {
    id : morphline1
    importCommands : ["org.kitesdk.**", "org.apache.solr.**"]
    commands :
    [
      { detectMimeType { includeDefaultMimeTypes : true } }
      {
        solrCell {
          solrLocator : ${solrLocator}
          captureAttr : true
          lowernames : true
          capture : [_attachment_body, _attachment_mimetype, basename, content, content_encoding, content_type, file, meta]
          parsers : [ { parser : org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser } ]
         }
      }
      { generateUUID { field : id } }
      { sanitizeUnknownSolrFields { solrLocator : ${solrLocator} } }
      { logDebug { format : "output record: {}", args : ["@{}"] } }
      { loadSolr: { solrLocator : ${solrLocator} } }
    ]
  }
]

Please help me what could be the issue
Regards,
~Sri
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally en flume logs you can see more detailed of your error, you can paste the trace?

May be morphilines doesnt find your solr configuration, you can add this property in your morphilines.conf

solrHomeDir : "/your_solr_config_files"

I hope it's your help